# Send PHP post without waiting to an answer

Tags: php, asynchronous, php-curl

I have a component in my PHP code that send a POST request to another third part server.
The problem is the other server is to slow and it take him a bit to return an answer.
I want my code to continue, without waiting to an answer (async).
Is there a way to do that?

This is my function:

```
function send_post_to_url($url,$post) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post));
    $return = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $return;
}
send_post_to_url("https://www.somesite.com",['action' => 'some_action']);
```

Thanks :)

Comment: You should contact the third party server for this, only they can help you here

Comment: Or a cron job could help you, depends on what you want to achieve

Comment: Unfortunately I can not do that, because its a world wide wordpress plugin who ran in many places on many services...